# Accord framework PrincipalComponentAnalysis on large data

Tags: accord.net

I'm using the Accord dotnet framework to do PrincipalComponentAnalysis.

I have a computed distance matrix, then I apply the KPCA on it:

```
Dim pca = new KernelPrincipalComponentAnalysis()
pca.Learn(distances)
pca.NumberOfOutputs = 2
Dim actual()() As double = pca.Transform(distances)
```

This is working well. However if the matrix is quite big (e.g 2000x2000), pca.learn takes several minutes.
Is there a way to learn with a sampling matrix (e.g 500x500) in order to transform the big matrix ?
I have tried:

```
pca.Learn(sampling)
pca.Transform(distances)
```

But I get an error because the matrix does not have the right size.

Best Regards
Jean-Michel

Comment: Are you trying to pass a distance matrix, or a kernel matrix? What you ask should actually be possible to do if what you are referring as a distance matrix is actually the kernel one.

Comment: Hi Cesar,

The matrix contains the calculated distance between documents e.g for 5 documents:
 Dim distances1 =
    {
       New Double() {0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
       New Double() {0.0, 0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
       New Double() {0.0, 0.0, 0, 1.0, 1.0},
       New Double() {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 0.0},
       New Double() {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0}
    }
a value of zero means documents are identicals.
Jean-Michel

Comment: Hi Cesar,

The matrix contains the calculated distance between documents.
e.g for 5 documents:
Dim distances1 =
    {
       New Double() {0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
       New Double() {0.0, 0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
       New Double() {0.0, 0.0, 0, 1.0, 1.0},
       New Double() {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 0.0},
       New Double() {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0}
    }

a value of zero means documents are identical.

Regards
Jean-Michel

Answer (score 0):

What you ask should be possible to do if the matrix you refer to as a distance matrix is actually a kernel matrix. Since you are using KPCA I am assuming this can be the case, so I will show below a way to create use KPCA learn and transform methods using kernel matrices with different sizes.

```
// Let's say those were our original data points
double[][] data =
{
    new double[] { 2.5,  2.4 },
    new double[] { 0.5,  0.7 },
    new double[] { 2.2,  2.9 },
    new double[] { 1.9,  2.2 },
    new double[] { 3.1,  3.0 },
    new double[] { 2.3,  2.7 },
    new double[] { 2.0,  1.6 },
    new double[] { 1.0,  1.1 },
    new double[] { 1.5,  1.6 },
    new double[] { 1.1,  0.9 }
};
```

Now, let's say that we already have their kernel matrix K available somehow. Note: a way to compute K would have been something similar to

```
double[] mean = data.Mean(dimension: 0);
double[][] x = data.Subtract(mean, dimension: 0);    
Linear kernel = new Linear();
double[][] K = kernel.ToJagged(x);
```

Now, assuming that K is already available, we can create a KPCA as

```
var pca = new KernelPrincipalComponentAnalysis(kernel, PrincipalComponentMethod.KernelMatrix);
```

And then learn it using

```
pca.Learn(K); // note: we pass the kernel matrix instead of the data points
```

For the example above, we would have

```
// Those are the expected eigenvalues, in descending order:
double[] eigenvalues = pca.Eigenvalues.Divide(data.Length - 1); //  { 1.28, 0.049 };

// And this will be their proportion:
double[] proportions = pca.ComponentProportions; // { 0.96, 0.03 };

// We can transform the inputs using
double[][] actual = pca.Transform(K);

// The output should be similar to
double[,] expected = new double[,]
{
    {  0.827970186, -0.175115307 },
    { -1.77758033,   0.142857227 },
    {  0.992197494,  0.384374989 },
    {  0.274210416,  0.130417207 },
    {  1.67580142,  -0.209498461 },
    {  0.912949103,  0.175282444 },
    { -0.099109437, -0.349824698 },
    { -1.14457216,   0.046417258 },
    { -0.438046137,  0.017764629 },
    { -1.22382056,  -0.162675287 },
}.Multiply(-1);
```

Now, finally, to answer the question about how to use our KPCA to transform a kernel matrix of a different size, we can use

```
double[][] newData = // this is a smaller matrix than the original
{
    new double[] { 2.2,  2.7 },
    new double[] { 1.2,  4.9 },
    new double[] { 1.8,  0.2 },
};

// Subtract the mean before computing a kernel matrix
double[][] y = newData.Subtract(mean, dimension: 0);

// Create the kernel matrix for new data
double[][] newK = kernel.ToJagged2(y, x);

// Transform using the new kernel matrix
double[][] output = pca.Transform(newK);

// Output will be similar to
double[][] expected = 
{
    new double[] { -0.845161763306007, -0.24880030917481 },
    new double[] { -1.78468140697569,  -2.47530044148084 },
    new double[] {  1.26393423496622,   1.15181172492746 }
};
```

Comment: Your example has 10 dimensions and consists of 2 data sets, right?

Comment: For converting the data array from 10 dimensions to 2 dimensions, is the newData array needed, and if where are the values from?